# Error-> Reading plist: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: xcode, react-native

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app requires access to the photo library</string>
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app requires access to the camera</string>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>en</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>kangaroohop</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app needs to access your location.</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>localhost</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                    <true/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <!-- <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> -->
        <true/>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <true/>
        <string/>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreenIntracept</string>
        <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
        <array>
            <string>armv7</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UIAppFonts</key>
        <array>
            <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
            <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
            <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
            <string>Feather.ttf</string>
            <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
            <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
            <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
            <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
            <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
            <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
            <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
            <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
            <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
            <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
            <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
            <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

I have been trying to build my app using Xcode and it is giving me this error. I have tried different other solutions which are previously mentioned on StackOverflow, but I cannot get rid of this error.

-> I am using the latest version of Xcode 12.5

-> My React Native version is 0.64.0

-> My info.plist file is :

Answer (score 0):

To solve you can copy/paste the XML into a template project.

The problem is that you have made some handmade edits to comment out a key-value pair and made invalid XML

Delete from line 44-48 to fix. The segment should be:

```
     <!-- <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> 
        <true/> 
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <true/>
        <string/> -->
```

not

```
<!-- <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> -->
        <true/>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <true/>
        <string/>
```

That will solve your immediate issue. From there you can add strings for the two keys in the Xcode editor.